# In Adobe Acrobat how do I set the spacing (single space or double space) of a content box?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I am running Adobe Arot XI version 11.0.0. How do I set the spacing (single space or double space) of a content box? I have searched the controls which appear on the right-hand-side of the application when I select `Edit | Edit Text & Images` from the menu pane, but couldn't find the option to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Which Acrobat version are you using?

Comment: See my updated post.

Comment: In my Acrobat 11.0.09, there is a discreet "+" button right of the Format title in the Content Editing pane in the Tools panel, and Edit Text & Images is active, and a suitable document is open. This button opens a few more properties, among them the leading in the paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

In Acrobat Pro DC:

1. Select Edit Text and Images.
2. On the right hand side, the Format Panel unlocks.
3. There is an Up/Down arrow where the lines are together and an Up/Down arrow where there is a space in the middle (under the justification icons).
4. I highlighted the section where I needed to adjust the scanned document and selected 1.5 in the box.  On my scanned PDF, the space looks like a double space.  2.0 was too big on the printout.  You can adjust as needed.